# Navigating IPFS Architecture Challenges: Managing Data Across Multiple Node

Tags: storage, blockchain, gateway, ipfs

I am currently running my own IPFS nodes and have accumulated about 500GB of data. I've observed that once a node stores over 100GB of data, certain bugs tend to occur, so I've opted to run multiple nodes. Currently, I'm managing six nodes.

My primary challenge lies in the management of these nodes. It's quite cumbersome to track which data resides on which node for the purpose of creating new DAGs. Also, the cost of data transfer between nodes is significantly high.

I'm seeking effective solutions to ease this management pain and reduce data transfer costs. What would be the recommended approach for handling such a situation in a more efficient way?

The approach I am currently trying involves having five IPFS nodes to store historical data, with one new IPFS node to store new data. When assembling DAGs, data is migrated from the old nodes to the new node. Then, I perform a deletion of duplicate data on a weekly basis